# concatenation not working as expected in java

Tags: java, input, string-concatenation

I expect an output of "I wrote a little code" (in the last line) when I enter "little code" as an input (in the last line), but the output is "I wrote a "
This is my code: `

```
String s = "I wrote a ";
int i = 4;
double j = 7.0; 
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String c; int a; double b;
a = scan.nextInt();
b = scan.nextDouble();
c = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(i + a);
System.out.println(j + b);
System.out.println(s + c);
scan.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually typing something into the console, and that this is the code causing your problem? **You need to press enter/make a newline** in order for `nextLine` to work.

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Comment: Are you using an online compiler ?

Comment: yes this is the code and I m using an online compiler

Comment: @MouadELFakir [Ideone](http://ideone.com/EmrwWp) works fine for me (quickly copy-pasted into default main method :P) OP: are you sure the code _is really printing_ `"I wrote a"` and exiting, or is it just not executing the second print as `nextLine` is stalling?

Comment: If using IdeOne, you need to give the input in the box. Online compilers don't pause for keyboard input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code is working fine for me:

```
String s = "I wrote a ";
int i = 4;
double j = 7.0; 
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String c; int a; double b;
a = scan.nextInt();
b = scan.nextDouble();
scan.nextLine();
c = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(i + a);
System.out.println(j + b);
System.out.println(s + c);
scan.close();
```

Was just missing that scan.nextLine() after b = scan.nextDouble();